# Alternative for spring-roo repository

Tags: java, maven, spring-roo

Any alternative for **https://repo.spring.io/spring-roo**? apparently today is down:

{
"errors" : [ {
"status" : 404,
"message" : "Not Found"
} ]
}

Comment: Seems to be working again

Answer (score 0):

this alternative its working for Spring-Roo and all dependencys of Spring:

https://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/